# JSP class attribute invalid

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am attempting to get to grips with a decent level of JSP quickly to build an interface.  I found what seems a good tutorial at this URL.

[Reference link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_tutorial.pdf)

While following the tutorial to the word, on page 35 it covers jsp:getProperty Action.  I successfully created the TestBean.java file and it compiled to produce TestBean.class.  But what I found was that my Tomcat's webapps directory did not contain a folder named `"WEB-INF" and so no directory "webapps\WEB-INF\classes\action"` so I added the `"WEB-INF\classes\action"` myself.  Then when I run the main.jsp file the browser states the following error

> "The value for the useBean class attribute action.TestBean is invalid"

What I am doing wrong?

Here is the Java "TestBean.class" code;

```
/* File: TestBean.java */

package action;

public class TestBean { 

private String message = "No message specified"; 

public String getMessage() { 
    return(message); 
} 

public void setMessage(String message) { 
    this.message = message; 
} 

}
```

And here is the JSP "main.jsp" code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using JavaBeans in JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>Using JavaBeans in JSP</h2>
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="action.TestBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="test" property="message" value="Hello JSP..." />
<p>Got message....</p>
<jsp:getProperty name="test" property="message" />
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to put the compiled file (`TestBean.class`) in `webapps\WEB-INF\classes\action`.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for response.  I did place the complied TestBean.class in the directory I created in webapps\WEB-INF\classes\action.

Comment: Also make sure the package is correct: `package action; public class TestBean...`

Comment: Thanks again Nikos.  I have just actually recreated and recompiled the TestBean.class by cutting and pasting the code directly from the tutorial.  Complied with no errors on command line.  Copied TestBean.class to actions directory again.  But the browser outputs the same result.

Comment: Is TestBean an Interface or a Class? What does your jsp:useBean tag look like? Can you show us its source and the source of the page that's trying to use it?

Comment: Thanks nitind. TestBean is a class. The jsp:useBean tag looks like this; <jsp:useBean id="test" class="action.TestBean" />. The tutorial is at the following link and the part going wrong is on page 35. I have followed it word for word, so you can see exactly what I am trying to do id you look at it. I am using notepad++ and command line. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are working on eclipse. 
If Web-INF is not created that means you are not working in a dynamic web project.

Go to NEW in eclipse. Go to Dynamic web project. It will create all you folders needed for a JSP/WEB project itself including Web-INF. This will stream line the process.

Other option is place your class files in required folder which is quite tedious job. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for response.  I am not using Eclipse for this.  Just using Notepad++ and command line and browser.

Comment: Thanks for update. Notepad++ is very tough to use considering it doesn't give you desired environment for trouble free development. I would advise you to shift to any IDE for problem free so that you don't have to track your folders and all other unnecessary things. For detailed solution please provide your source here so that I can analyze your code better.

Comment: Thanks Angular Harsh. I have posted the code for the part that is causing me problems by editing into the original question.  AJFarroll